# Why doesn't video-conferencing with subtitles exist?

Tags: translation, voice-recognition, subtitle, video-conferencing, closed-captions

Voice-to-text has existed for a long time, and is built into every major desktop and mobile OS.
Video conferencing exists on many platforms and across many protocols.
Language translation tools can run locally or in the cloud.

Why is it so difficult to add subtitles, in multiple languages, to video conferencing?

Real-time voice-to-text (closed captioning) is available on a few platforms, but absent from many. Why are so many missing this when the benefits are so great?

And why can't I view closed captions translated into my native language? We know the translations won't be perfect - but surely this cannot be so difficult to achieve?

I have tried several video-conferencing platforms from major vendors, and none of them seem to address this area well.

Comment: Here is a dated, but relevant, survey of captioning available in teleconferencing platforms written by a deaf person: https://meryl.net/best-automatic-captioning-tool-for-video-calls/#comparison

Comment: Hello Shane: these questions are probably better asked to the maintainers of the platforms you had in mind when composing your message. For topics related to Stack Overflow, see [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask).